# Проблема с запуском minion - Kohana3 // Cron

Tags: php, cron, kohana

Не могу уже 3-й день настроить модуль и корректно запуститься, помогите пожалуйста с решением проблемы.

Вся проблема что при запуске команд: ./minion {task} --help или php index.php --uri=minion --task={task} выводит терминал html код с ошибкой - который не несет в себе информативности об ошибке) тупо набор тегов.

Cron при запуске простых файлов html отрабатывается - проблема в структуре Kohana - ее путях файлах и т.д. поэтому я полагаю Cron и не срабатывает. Поэтому нашел вариант с модулем Minion - настроил как в инструкции - и хоть убей не запускается. Не дает нужного ответа команда - тупо тег как писал выше.

Comment: Выдает этот код: https://github.com/kohana/kohana2/blob/master/system/views/kohana/error.php

Comment: вот ошибка: ErrorException [ Warning ]: Declaration of Kohana_Minion_Exception::handler(Exception $e) should be compatible with Kohana_Kohana_Exception::handler($e)

Comment: Решил... по всей видимости модуль старый - не тянет php 7

Answer (score 1):

Решил... по всей видимости модуль старый - не тянет php 7